# Specifying % in href causing issue in IE

Tags: html, anchor

As a business requirement i want anchor tag with `%` in the href.For eg
`href="abc/a% bc.txt` `target="_blank"`
This works in Chrome but it doesn't work in IE.
Can anybody help me in resolving this IE issue?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Cheers,
Sajesh Nambiar

Comment: HOW IT does not work please provide jsfiddle

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Why is a % in a link a business rule?

Comment: or if possible provide your website link

Comment: The txt filename itself doesn't seem to be a valid file name ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**escape**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.escape)d version of "`abc/a% bc.txt`" string:

```
href="abc/a%25%20bc.txt"
```

Comment: Theres a whol list of symbols that need to be encoded - for example % is in the Unsafe characters section at the end of this article http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm

Comment: @mouters Only `2` symbols need to be encoded, so using `escape` method is fully suitable in this case.

Comment: In this particular case - yes.